# Make [hextiles] a synonym of [hexagonal-tiles]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[hextiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hextiles) has 20 tagged questions, of which all appear to refer to hexagonal tiles or hex-binning, which has its own [hexagonal-tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-tiles) tag with 78 questions.

I assert that it's a good candidate for a synonym, and I wish I had a witty headline involving the word "adjacency."

Comment: What is the tag for? The wiki for [tag:hexagonal-tiles] mentions "The use of this tag is fairly broad, encompassing statistics, computer science and game design." which is fair game for burnination usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bharghav Rao did this with their moderator powers.

Comment: Just FYI, the [status-completed] tag is how we indicate this was done. There's no need to self-answer or bump old requests